# How does computer really request data in a computer?

Tags: memory-management, cpu, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment

I was wondering how exactly does a CPU request data in a computer. In a 32 Bits architecture, I thought that a computer would put a destination on the address bus and would receive 4 Bytes on the data bus. I recently read on the memory alignment in computer and it confused me. I read that the CPU has to read two times the memory to access a not multiple 4 address. Why is so? The address bus lets it access not multiple 4 address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address bus itself, even in a 32-bit architecture, is usually not 32 bits in size. E.g. [the Pentium's address bus was 29 bits](http://books.google.com/books?id=TVzjEZg1--YC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=pentium%20address%20lines&source=bl&ots=iB1ARMt0E-&sig=0XwDYIiKSeXCjMRH0_TB-VwuDWM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eaRFVLbbDaSrjALpjYHIDA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pentium%20address%20lines&f=false). Given that it has a full 32-bit range, in the Pentium's case that means each slot in memory is eight bytes wide. So reading a value that straddles two of those slots means two reads rather than one, and alignment prevents that from happening.

Other processors (including other implementations of the 32-bit Intel architecture) have different memory access word sizes but the point is generic.

Comment: So, with a 32 bits width data bus, the address on the address bus refer only to the 32 bits slots? I thought the slots width was completly independent from the data bus width. My understanding of it is if you put an address on the add. bus, it will give the byte at this address and the 3 after to form a 4 bytes data vector. It this case the slots would be 1 byte long, I though it was always the case in common RAM

Comment: No, in many cases, including the Pentium as the example I could most easily find a link for, the address bus omits the lowest few bits and the processor just chops and glues to hide the difference. I should also point out that things like cache lines often work analogously but even more coarsely, so compound structures can sometimes benefit from even greater alignment.